# indexOf solo retorna la primera posicion

Tags: vue.js

```
     <v-row class="justify-center pa-0 ma-0">
          <v-col cols="12" md="6" lg="6">
            <v-card
              outlined
              v-for="(item, index) in tasks"
              :key="index"
              class="py-3 px-3 my-2 overline"
            >
              <v-row>
                <v-col cols="12" md="1" lg="1" class="pa-0 ma-0">
                  <v-checkbox
                    class="mx-4"
                    :input-value="checked"
                    @click="validateCheckBox"
                  
                  ></v-checkbox>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="12" md="3" lg="3" class="align-self-center pa-0">
                  {{ index + 1 }}
                  {{ item }}
                </v-col>
              </v-row>
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>

  export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      tarea: "",
      tasks: [],
      checked: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addTask() {
      this.tasks.push(this.tarea);
      this.tarea = "";
       console.log(this.tasks)
    },
    validateCheckBox(){
      if(this.checked){
        this.checked = true;
         let index = this.tasks.indexOf(this.tarea)
         console.log('indice',index)
         this.tasks.splice(index,1)
      }
    }
  },
};
```

Buenas tardes estoy practicando Vue.js y estoy haciendo una todolist,pero al momento de recoger el indice para borrar  me  retorna siempre la posicion 0 haciendo que el método  split borre elementos pero, aleatorios ya que todas mis tasks son posicion 0, espero que me puedan echar la mano para poder aprender

Comment: `this.tarea` es un string vacío... ¿en qué momento toma un valor?

Comment: Es lo que se me ocurrió , no se si se podra con el index del v-for

Comment: Sí, pero no se entiende que quieres que suceda. ¿Cuando clickas el checkbox quieres que se elimine el elemento del array? no sería más lógico un botón de eliminar? o por qué un checkbox?

Comment: pues es que ubuntu lo tiene así, cuando pones el checkbox en true  la borra , y bueno lo que quiero hacer es que cuando pponga el checkbox la tarea se elimine, cosa que si puedo hacer, solo que si elimino la tarea dos  se elimina la 3, solo funciona bien si las elimino de abajo para arriba pero yo no quiero eso

Comment: No sé si te entiendo, pero puedes pasarle directamente el index al método que se encarga de borrar `@click="validateCheckBox(index)"`, y en el método lo recibes como argumento. Lo de que el valor del checkbox sea true es indiferente, si los checkbox no van a pasar nunca a valor false, pues cuando pasan a true se eliminan